# Correct way to fix knockout typescript compiler error after upgrading to 0.9.5

Tags: knockout.js, typescript

Just upgraded typescript from 0.9.1.1 to 0.9.5 and am seeing compiler errors with lines like this:

```
prop: KnockoutObservable<string> = ko.observable();
```

The error is:

```
Cannot convert KnockoutObservable<{}> to KnockoutObservable<string>
```

I read about the breaking changes, but I am wondering, what is the correct fix for this?

This seems to work, and I think it's functionally correct, at least if/until knockout.d.ts is changed to accommodate the new compiler changes:

```
prop: KnockoutObservable<string> = ko.observable(undefined);
```

However, I still can't find a fix for observableArrays:

```
prop: KnockoutObservableArray<string> = ko.observableArray(undefined); // compiler error
prop: KnockoutObservableArray<string> = ko.observableArray([]); // compiler error
```

Update:

Just found out this works for observableArray. Need to cast undefined:

```
prop = ko.observableArray(<string[]>undefined); // builds
```

Because of the casting in the function argument, the type of the array is cast correctly.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It seems `ko.observable` and `ko.observableArray` should be updated to be generic so:

```
prop: KnockoutObservable<string> = ko.observable<string>();
prop: KnockoutObservableArray<string> = ko.observableArray<string>();
```

Comment: I had no idea you could do that! With the type inferrence on the right side of the assignment operator, you don't even need `: KnockoutObservable<string>`, right?